# What does a status of "P" mean during a Tortoise CVS Update operation?

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

I ran an "Update" command on a folder with TortoiseCVS and one of the file statuses is "P". What does that mean? I see "U" which I'm assuming means "Update" and "M" which I'm assuming means "Merge". I tried to open the help file but I'm just getting 404s, so I think the firewall at my office is blocking the help contents...

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing:
[image]
<sub>(source: [chomperstomp.com](http://www.chomperstomp.com/img/whatIsTheP.png))</sub>

Comment: This is actually not specific to TortoiseCVS. In fact, I think most CVS implementations use the same file status codes. The CVS client that TortoiseCVS uses internally is based on code from WinCVS and [CVSNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CVSNT), so those projects are the best bets for finding official documentation about the underlying CVS implementation. Specifically regarding your question, the full list of status codes (including "P") can be found in [this documentation for the update command](http://cvsnt.org/manual2/html/update.html).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's equivalent to a 'U', but CVS figured that sending a patch rather than the whole updated file would be smaller.

I couldn't quickly find a fuller explanation, but here's [a table of codes](http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/116/).

Comment: Chose this as the answer due to it having the table of codes linked. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6):

P stands for patch. It means only a small update was made, so the whole file did not need to be sent.

Answer (score 6):

According to various sources, P refers to a file patched individually rather than updated (U).

See http://www.gjt.org/mlist/jcvs/msg01480.html and a bunch of others except I'm a new user so I can only post one link :-( for details.

I couldn't find any docs specifically for Tortoise CVS that explained this though.